# What is the procedure for installing an external framework or library for Swift in XCode 6?

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks

I want to create a new XCode 6 Swift project and install this framework: https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter. The instructions on the framework's github page itself seem incomplete, and in searching for the full instructions I have Googled, and StackOverflowed, and tried many things without success, so I'm left with the recourse to questioning.  Thank you in advance. MJB.

Comment: Please read **Installation** steps under **Getting Started** on the same page.

Comment: Rahul, come on, I have. They are too vague and I have tried.

Comment: Rahul, the link that cnoon provided below was much more detailed and worked. The **Installation** steps under **Getting Started** on the same page made some assumptions about the prior knowledge of the person reading them that were simply not true for me. I am completely new to XCode and knew nothing of its build phases and dependencies. But thanks for your input anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are really awesome installation instructions for frameworks in the Alamofire README [Embedded Framework](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) section. Please note that you will need to swap the Alamofire specific information for `Swifter`.

You could also consider using [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage). There are also some great instructions for Carthage use in the Alamofire README [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#carthage).

Comment: Thanks cnoon, the instructions on that page were excellent for anyone who is new to XCode. Like me!

Comment: Awesome...glad to hear it!