# Install Swifter framework to Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to install Swifter framework to Xcode that provided by github here:
https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter

but the installation is not clear enough, there is no folder had the extenssion .framework with header folder inside it
can someone please help me how to get this framework to my project

thank you

Comment: thank you. the installation instructions are a joke lol

Comment: this is a MUCH better explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078125/what-is-the-procedure-for-installing-an-external-framework-or-library-for-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should clone the repo. After that drag and drop `Swifter.xcodeproj` to your project. Lastly add `SwifteriOS.framework` to linked frameworks and libraries of your project.

Answer (score 7):

IF you are using Cocoapods, add the following line to your Podfile.

```
pod 'Swifter', :git => 'https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter.git'
```

Run `pod install` then you should be set.