# Swifter Twitter Set Up

Tags: swift, xcode, import, cocoapods, swifter

I am trying to add Swifter to my Xcode Swift project, but I keep getting the `No such Module` error. I followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50870124/6675801) instructions to download them using pods. But now I keep getting the error when I try to `import SwifteriOS`. I have also tried manually adding the framework to both the `Embedded Binaries` and `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` found on the `Target` -> `General` Page. [image]

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more playing around with it, it seems like `import SwifteriOS` has been renamed to just `import Swifter`. This got rid of any compile errors that I had. I also ended up deleting the `Swifter.framework` from all three spots in the photo above with no issues. 

I think the docs may be a little bit outdated as well as the example project! Hope this helped someone else!

Comment: how are you able to do authentication properly, I am having problems. Please see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413915/new-twitter-update-authentication thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are TWO Swifter pods!!! its important to add this extra piece to your podfile:

```
pod 'Swifter' , :git => 'https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter.git'
```

to see how to set up the rest i have answered the question with an update (for 2021) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005919/how-to-authorize-twitter-with-swifter/66956121#66956121)