# New Twitter update authentication

Tags: swift, authentication, twitter, safari, swifter

I'm making a twitter app on iOS using their api. But they just recently upgraded everything dealing with authentication.  Therefore breaking The [Swifter](https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter) library that I am using. My app was working fine before this update. In my apps.twitter.com In the setting section, the first callback url I have is http://MyTweeter ...It wants to me to add another callback, idk why/what so I just added http://google.com. In my app when I call the authentication function, it starts to authenticate and goes to the twitter login page and right after I click the login button it shows me the error in the pic attached below "Safari cannot open the page because the server cannot be found". [image: smh] Does any one have a solution?

Comment: I have posted an answer with a 2021 update here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005919/how-to-authorize-twitter-with-swifter/66956121#66956121

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution. In you app, in the authentication function, your callback url should be something like `MyTwitter://success` but in apps.twitter.com you have to make it `MyTwitter://` without the second part